# Characteristic functions in set theory

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, elementary-set-theory, characteristic-functions

The book I am studying has the definition of a characteristic function as follows.

Let $A\subseteq{X}$.  Then

$$\chi_A(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x\in{A}$} \\
0, & \text{if $x\in{X-A}$}  \\
\end{cases}
$$

The two cases where I know a characteristic function has been defined is in Linear Algebra where the characteristic function of a matrix is $\det(\lambda{I}-A)=0$ and in Differential Equations where the characteristic function of a linear nth order ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients is determined by letting $r^i=\frac{d^iy}{dt^i}$ and setting the polynomial equal to zero.  My questions are these;

1)  In the linear algebra case, what would the space $X$ be?  by looking at the function defined above I'm assuming it's the set of all square matrices but then what is $A$?  And under what conditions do we need to know when $\det(\lambda{I}-A)=1$?  Or would it be instead $\det(A)=1$ implying something to do with the $SL$ group?  I'm confused.

2) how does this set theoretic definition above help explain roots of nth order linear ode's wiht constant coefficients?

Comment: There is no useful connection between the set-theoretic notion and the linear algebra notion. A word can have several distinct mathematical meanings. Another example is field as it is used in algebra, and field of sets as it is used in measure theory.

Comment: What's more, the LA and DE ones are more than functions, they are characteristic polynomials.

Comment: I guess my original assumption was that since set theory permeates the different branches of math, that the set theoretic idea of a characteristic function would have a logical connection to these other areas.  If I recall recurrence relations also have characteristic functions as well.  Is there a connection between set theory and differential equations?  And would this notion mentioned above be more comparable to an indicator function such as the ones used in Probability theory?

Comment: It's quite *normal* that the same notion has different meanings in different branches of mathematics. Quiz: Find as many different meanings of "normal" as possible.

Comment: This meaning of "characteristic function" is _the same thing_ as what other authors prefer to call an "indicator function".

Comment: okay, so this is simply just a particular idea within set theory that essentially is an {off / on} switch.  If something is an element of the subset in question it get a 1 and if something is not an element, it gets a 0.  Plain and simple?

Comment: so if i have a mapping $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow{\{0,1\}}$ where $f(x)=x\mod{2}$, this constitutes a characteristic function if $A=2\mathbb{Z}+1\subset{\mathbb{Z}}$ right?

Comment: Yes. Any mapping $f : X \to \{0,1\}$ is an indicator function of some set ($f^{-1}\{1\}$).